# Did something change/break with Google Directory API over the weekend?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Starting this morning, I am unable to set orgUnitPath on a User object using raw HTTP protocol.

```
PATCH /admin/directory/v1/users/testuser_1440432547467%40example.com

{"orgUnitPath":"/testorgunit_2"}
```

returns

```
{
  "error": {
     "errors": [ {
       "domain":"global",
       "reason":"invalid",
       "message":"Invalid Input: Inconsistent Orgunit id and path in request - 8100451664789505, /testorgunit_2"}],
     "code":400,
     "message":"Invalid Input: Inconsistent Orgunit id and path in request - 8100451664789505, /testorgunit_2"
  }
}
```

OrgUnit ID doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but I'm also noticing that the data coming back from the Directory API does now include an orgUnitID property in addition to the orgUnitPath property.

```
{
  ...
  orgUnitId=id:02gyr1s20gshpvd,
  orgUnitPath=/
}
```

Can anyone confirm if there was an API change that now requires orgUnitId to be also be supplied in addition to orgUnitPath or if this is a bug that was just introduced?

Comment: I am having the same issue, however there has not been any changes in the revision history: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/revision-history?hl=en

Comment: It appears Google has either rolled back or fixed the API change that caused this issue - thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

This is most definitely a bug. For instance, the Google Apps Directory Sync tool which makes use of the API is also affected and there is not an update for the tool.

Answer (score 3):

There has been [a bug filed](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3987). I suggest you star the issue and add any relevant info you can to help this issue get fixed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, switching to users.update() instead of patch should work until Google fixed the issue. No modifications to the body should be needed.